# In need of a SNMP repeater

Tags: linux, snmp, udp, repeater

I have a monitoring system that has primary/failover nodes for just about every aspect.  I have configured anything that is able for multiple SNMP trap destinations, but I do have a number of devices that only support a single trap destination.

What I would like to do is configure a middleware service (On a RHEL/Linux server) that receives a UDP packet, and re-transmits it to multiple SNMP receivers, effectively acting as a repeater.

I'm not sure what services exist out there, but I ultimately I want to configure devices to trap to 1 single IP address and the device that owns that IP address be responsible for forwarding it everywhere else. If a given node is down it is of no consequence because the trap destinations are clustered anyway.

Comment: You could use Iptables to forward the requests (SNMP is udp/162).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/samplicator/

> This simple program listens for UDP datagrams on a network port, and
>   sends copies of these datagrams on to a set of destinations.
>   Optionally, it can perform sampling, i.e. rather than forwarding every
>   packet, forward only 1 in N. Another option is that it can "spoof" the
>   IP source address, so that the copies appear to come from the original
>   source, rather than the relay. Currently only supports IPv4.
>
> It can been used to distribute e.g. Netflow packets, SNMP traps (but
>   not informs), or Syslog messages to multiple receivers.

Answer (score 4):

Such a thing is called a relay, not a repeater. Suprisingly, googling for snmp trap relay gives no useful results, the closest I got was [a piece of code to implement such a thing on windows](http://sourceforge.net/p/snmpsharpnet/discussion/885529/thread/c800a88a), which isn't very close at all.

Looks like you need to build your own.